# Generate SAML request using Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, opensaml

I am working on an SSO integration that is SP initiated. I have started with an API that will generate an SAML request and convert it into an URL that the frontend will redirect. Following is the code for generating the URL that consists SAML request.

```
String redirectUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/f8ceef31-c65g-4b4a-09e4-5f571x91255a\r\n" + "/saml2"
                + "?SAMLRequest=";

        String samlRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol\" "
                + "xmlns:saml=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\" " + "ID=\"" + Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
                + "Version=\"2.0\" " + "IssueInstant=\"" + Instant.now() + "\" "
                + "ProtocolBinding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST\" "
                + "AssertionConsumerServiceURL=\"https://login.microsoftonline.com/1ebc9492-2234-472a-87v5-ea64ae60db97/saml2\">"
                + "<saml:Issuer>https://login.microsoftonline.com/1ebc9497-2161-672a-84b4-ea64ae60db97/saml2</saml:Issuer>"
                + "<samlp:NameIDPolicy Format=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified AllowCreate=\"true\"/>"
                + "</samlp:AuthnRequest>";

        byte[] compressedBytes = new byte[samlRequest.length()];
        Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, true);
        deflater.setInput(samlRequest.getBytes());
        deflater.finish();
        int compressedSize = deflater.deflate(compressedBytes);
        deflater.end();

        String base64Encoded = Base64.getEncoder()
                .encodeToString(Arrays.copyOfRange(compressedBytes, 0, compressedSize));

        String relayStateString = redirectUrl + base64Encoded;
```

When the URL is generated and I try to redirect I encounter the following error.

`SAML message was not properly base64-encoded.`

Earlier I used the `spring-security-saml-dsl` dependency but failed to generate the SAMLRequest.

I have tried multiple ways of generating the SAML request but I have not able to successfully generate a correct URL that will redirect me to the login page

Answer (score 0):

The following link answered my question.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/580306/aadsts750056-saml-message-was-not-properly-base64

I missed the part where I had to URL encode the (Deflate + Base64) string and that is why it was giving me the error I shared.